# Database structure that can effectively gauge trends and popularity?

Tags: php, mysql, data-structures, data-modeling

Let's say I have a website with various assortments of widgets. These widgets are subject to being 'Liked' by a user. Well, how would I be able to gauge the popularity of any given widget in a certain time-span using the 'likes' as a measurement?. I can assemble scripts that are able to discern what is the hot widget today, or this week, month (and so on).

I was previously thinking of just tallying up the total likes, but that wouldn't be able to tell me if it were popular or not seeing is how there would be no bearing on time.

Comment: This question is rather broad. It would be helpful to know [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) or what your current line of thinking is as to how to implement it.

Comment: Just edited, sorry for that. It was broad. Hope that narrows it up.

Comment: +1 for the question in its new form :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 CREATE TABLE WidgetLikes (
     WidgetID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Widgets(WidgetID), 
     UserID   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(UserID),
     LikedAt DATETIME NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (WidgetID, UserID)
 );
```

This assumes:

1. The Widgets table holds a list of widgets, and has an integer primary key called WidgetID.
2. The Users table holds a list of users, and has a VARCHAR(20) primary key called UserID.
3. Each user is allowed to "like" a widget a maximum of one time.
4. You want to be able to track trends over periods shorter than a day as well as longer periods.

To use this table, INSERT a record whenever a user likes a widget.

To get results issue a command like:

```
 SELECT WidgetID, COUNT(UserID) FROM WidgetLikes 
    WHERE LikedAt BETWEEN `2012-09-01 00:00:00` AND `2012-09-03 11:59:59';
```

Comment: This was kind of what I had been thinking, but I feared it might be too cumbersome.

Comment: Seems pretty lightweight to me, and gives you the flexibility you desire.

Comment: Yah, that query convinced me. It is when there are a *bunch* of queries is when it gets bogged down.